# Standard deviation after a non-linear transformation of a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, means

I have two questions for you that have been bothering me for quite some time now.

**For the first one**

I have a normal distribution (density function `f(x)`) on which I only now the mean and standard deviation.

I have to apply a non-linear transformation over the variable `x`, let's call `k` the new transformed variable, defined as: `k = x ^ -2`

If `x_mean` is the mean of my first normal distribution, then can the new mean be calculated as : `k_mean = x_mean ^ -2`

Now, for the standard deviation I guess it's a bit different, here's what I did:

```
k_std = k_mean * (x_std / x_mean)
```

Does it make sense to you? Let's suppose `(x_mean / x_std)*100 = 7%`, then I assumed that `(k_mean / k_std)*100 = 7%`. What do you think?

**For the second question**

I have a square of length `2a` in which they are random points. I need to know the mean and std of the induced normal distribution of these points. However, I only know the mean and std of small parts of this square.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvtzf.jpg)

I know how to sum up all the small square mean to get the total one. However, for the std I have some doubts.

Here's what I would do (btw, in this example all the small squares have an equal surface, but it may not be always true):

[std equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awKer.png)

What do you think?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Beware : The mean of a function need not be the function of the mean.